# How to use Redis with loopback-MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, redis, loopback

I am looking into caching for api. I found redis.

I have read documentation from loopback [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Redis-connector.html)

But i am not sure how to connect/use it in loopback. My datasource.json is given below.

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mongoConnector": {
    "url": "${CONNECTION_STRING}",
    "name": "mongoConnector",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

If i add

```
"redisDS": {
  "name": "redisDS",
  "connector": "redis",
}
```

It gives me error. Probably because of "redisDS".

Can anyone explain how to create redis datasource or link it to mongodb.

Or how to use redis with loopback-mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use Redis as your datasource, since the data should still be stored in mongo. I haven't used it personally, but there is a mixin for loopback that will cache data in Redis and retrieve it from there on a per-model basis: https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-redis-cache